# How to check if a contact has an active membership in a smarty template?

Tags: email, message-templates, smarty

Is there a variable that one can use in smarty in a message template to simply determine if a contact has an active membership?

Answer (score 4):

Don't think you have a direct variable to use in the template. Worth trying an extension to provide this? It can be done by simply writing something like below in your hook.

```
function yourextension_civicrm_postProcess($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == "your_form") {

    //Check if user has an active membership of type "General".
    $activeMembership = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'getcount', array(
      'contact_id' => <contact_id in $form>,
      'active_only' => 1,
      'membership_type_id' => "General",
    ));

    //Assign a new variable to the template.
    $form->assign('activeMembership', $activeMembership);
  }
}
```

You can now use this variable as `{$activeMembership}` in the template to check if user has a membership of the req type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CiviCRM api through smarty to retrieve if membership is active for a contact. You can achieve this by

1. Turn on CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY (set to TRUE or 1) in civicrm.settings.php
2. add below api snippet in your message template

($result will hold result of api call)

```
{capture assign=contactId}{contact.contact_id}{/capture}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Membership' action='getcount' sequential=0 contact_id=$contactId membership_type_id="General" active_only=1}
{if $result gt 0} 
  'active membership'
{else}
  'not active'
{/if}
```

HTH

Pradeep